# itemize inside a node breaks when no text width is given

Tags: tikz-pgf, itemize

The following code breaks with `! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
     \node {%
        \begin{itemize}
            \item{Won't work} 
        \end{itemize}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

But this compiles just fine:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
     \node[text width=2cm] {%
        \begin{itemize}
            \item{Works} 
        \end{itemize}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Is this a limitation of `TikZ` in general or am I on an older version?

Comment: It's a general limitation in TeX: it must know the text width in order to typeset a paragraph.

Comment: I voted as a duplicate, since it's essentially the same problem as in the linked question.

Comment: @egreg It is indeed, didn't even dawn on me to search for other list types. I'm happy to close it but would maybe suggest generalising the original question to other list types so it can be found easier.